# Cómo crear dos claves foráneas de una misma tabla dentro de una entidad en active record migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Necesito crear una entidad ProductsRequests en rails que tenga dos columnas user_request y user_response, las cuales sean claves foráneas de mi tabla users.
Estoy utilizando rails 5.1 y ruby 2.7.1
Estoy aprendiendo, soy nuevo en ruby

Migración productsrequests

```
class ProductsRequests < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :products_requests do |t|
    end
  end
end
```

MIgracion users

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      # t.string :id, null:false, default: ""
      t.string :first_name, null: false, default: ''
      t.string :last_name, null: true, default: ''
      t.string :dni, null: false, default: ''
      t.string :telephone, null: true, default: ''
      t.date :date_of_birth, null: true, default: ''
      t.string :role, null: false, array: true, default: []
      t.boolean :active, null: false, default: true
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ''
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ''

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    add_index :users, :dni,                  unique: true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end
end
```

Modelo user:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  belongs_to :enterprise, optional: true
  has_many :product_request, optional: true

  def is_active
    return { message: 'user cant log in' } unless active
  end
end
```

modelo ProductRequest

```
class ProductRequest < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, optional: false
  belongs_to :stock, optional: false
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu migración debería ser como:

```
create_table :products_requests do |t|
    t.references :user_request, foreign_key: {to_table: :users}
    t.references :user_response, foreign_key: {to_table: :users}
end
```

y en el modelo:

```
  belongs_to :user_request, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :user_response, class_name: 'User'
```